# AD LDS With Exchange Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, exchange

is possible to intall exchange server 2010 with Active directory lighwight Directory services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO.

You can only install the Edge Transport role with ADLDS (AKA Active Directory Application Mode). All of the other roles require a full fledged Active Directory setup.